# What is best practise for Data Contract management?

Tags: unit-tests, database

We are implementing a testing framework, covering areas like mentioned in [this SE article](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48237/what-is-an-integration-test-exactly/48265#48265). But in addition, as part of unit testing (probably), we want to perform **data contract testing**.

The database is in SQL Server and the schema is managed through Visual Studio git code repository.

My question is **are there best practices for data contract management** that cover:

- where the data contract meta-data is stored
- how is the data contract meta-data accessed

In order to execute our data contract tests automatically, the management of the meta-data needs to be in an electronic form that is programmatically accessible - e.g. a SQL table. Also, we want to be able to include the information into word documents or PDFs becoming part of the system documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Not I am not aware of any best practices.
One choice is to rely on an ORM.  The updates can be async so you'll want to avoid checking it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael, could you elucidate around ORM (I'm assuming Object-relational mapping) please? Not familiar (and it will assist others who come later). thanks

Comment: This issue we have is a number of teams working on separate databases (OLTP / DWH) and wanting to have an agreed data structure that is easily tested against change.